# split a data frame depends on csv file size using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

I have a very large data frame, with over a million records, and 5 columns.
I want to save this data frame to csv and split it to parts, so that each file, while zipped, is maximum ~500MB in size.
Is it possible to do it without saving the data frame to my machine and check it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't know CSV file size without saving it. It's possible to save part of big DataFrame and use it's file size to estimate size per row.

```
import pandas as pd

big_df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.np.random.randn(int(2e6), 5))

big_df.iloc[:100000].to_csv('temp.csv')

# look at temp.csv file size - 100 000 rows is 10 MB for me
# if I want about 50 MB per file I store to CSV a half million rows
# set it manually or you can compute it with os.path.getsize('temp.csv')
rows_max = int(5e5)

row_from = 0
row_to = rows_max
file_n = 1

while True:
    fn_i = 'big_%s.csv' % str(file_n).zfill(3)
    big_df.iloc[row_from:row_to].to_csv(fn_i)

    if row_to > big_df.index.size:
        break

    row_from = row_to
    row_to = row_from + rows_max
    file_n += 1
```